# Jenkins Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am building a Docker Image into Jenkinsfile Groovy Script.
I'm facing below error while creating the Docker Image.

[image]

Since ,docker has been installed automatically by Jenkins, so can't start it manually.

any Idea how can i do this by Jenkins by Script or an other around..?

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing jenkins on windows or linux?

If it is linux, you need to add user jenkins to the docker group

```
usermod -a -G docker jenkins
```

If it is windows, you need to go to serivces and log on jenkins as administrator.

[image]

Select tab logon --> Log in with a user with administrator rights

[image]

Then, restart service jenkins.

Comment: Thanks for your revert. I have installed Jenkins on Linux EC2. Do you want me to run "usermod -a -G docker jenkins" from Putty itself or via Jenkins Script.

Comment: `usermod -a -G docker jenkins`
from Putty (Note: you must run as root user or user with sudo privileges)